# Downloading Rust crates using a web browser

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there any way to download Rust dependencies using a web browser? I currently have internet access through my web browser but not through the command prompt (Windows).

I know that I can set up a local fileserver and [set Cargo to use a mirror](https://gmjosack.github.io/posts/dissecting-cratesio-minimum-mirror/), but that doesn't help if I can't get the crates in the first place.

**Edit:**

See related [Github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io/issues/65), now closed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following address:

`https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/name/version/download`

To download crates directly from [crates.io](https://crates.io/) - just change the `name` and `version` to download a specific version of a crate.

The downloaded file has a .crate extension, but it's actually a tarball (.tar.gz).

Comment: Looks like it's been open for a while :(

Comment: @yinnonsanders the GitHub issue is now closed - you can download crates directly with the browser (see updated answer). A very swift resolution from the crates.io team :).

Comment: Wow, sounds like I should start commenting on github issues more. So glad this happened! Thank you!